# I was fired because salary be leaked, could I still do anything now

Tags: salary, human-resources, offices, confidentiality

Someone checked my salary slip when I am not in my seat (and I forgot to lock the screen).
After that, he share what he read to my manager, and my manager hate me because he think my salary is nearly the same as his.

After short time, my manager fired me, he use the reason is my performance can not pass the probation.

After I talked with HR, they suggest me voice out my concern, even I don't have any evidence. However, I don't want my manager could walk away so easily, I think at least he need to pay for what he did to me. So, what else I should do? (I mean, in civilization way, office thing, no criminal direction)

Comment: Where are you from ? I you want to push things further, you could always ask a lawyer about unfair dismissal laws. However, if you have no proof and you were in a probation period, I'm no sure there is much you can do

Comment: Your location decides what those terms like "probation" even mean legally. You could get a lawyer, but "my boss hates me" is neither criminal nor otherwise illegal. If they had the power to fire you legally (the term "probation" makes that sound plausible) then there is little you can do.

Comment: I think it's more likely you were fired for not locking your screen than for how much someone else decided to pay you -- doubtless they'll decide to pay your replacement the same. But it doesn't matter if you were on probation - basically during probation you can be fired for pretty much any reason. If HR thought your manager did a bad thing, they might fire your manager, but that has nothing to do with you: you don't work there any more.

Comment: How do you know someone looked at your salary slip and how do you know your manager got this information? I also wonder your manager doesn't know your salary anyway.

Comment: @KateGregory , the thing is, my manager didn't mention the screen issue. He rejected all the other managers persuade, and line to everyone about why he fire me. (even include his supervisor). the only reason is because my salary is nearly like him. And HR help me to confirm this is truth.

Comment: @Vincent, Did HR help you confirm that your salaries are close or that your manager fired you because they are close?  Salaries being close doesn't prove that is why he fired you.

Comment: How do you know that this isn't just down to poor performance? Did your manager admit it when you mentioned it to him?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make clear. I make clear here: My manager said my performance is not good. but my technical lead (it should technical lead judge my performance, not my manager) help me to persuade him, not help. In the 121 meeting, he himself said my salary is close to him. @cdkMoose

Comment: Sorry I didn't make clear. I make clear here: My manager said my performance is not good. but my technical lead (it should technical lead judge my performance, not my manager) help me to persuade him, not help. In the 121 meeting, he himself said my salary is close to him @Unfair-Ban

Comment: Actually it is very clear he is not talking about my performance. Because my direct tutor, acknowledged my performance, and my technical lead, try his best to stop I being fired until the last second. And my technical lead actually should be the most powerful to say my performance is good or not. @Unfair-Ban

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd think that means he's firing you because of your salary. He said your performance was poor. He's not obliged to mindlessly agree with your technical lead who thinks different. He presumably mentioned your salary to highlight the expectations you aren't meeting.

Comment: well, I have no intend to talk about the performance issue, because I am on site there, I see more things. So I really don't want to argue with you about "I fired because performance or not". But of course you are right, he no need to agree with anyone, or even not need to have a reason to fire me. But I want to ask you a question: It seems on your mind, this manager allow other people to check sensitive thing in untrusted environment, fire ppl for other reason, seems all is NO-NEED-TO-MENTION. would I know why? because he is a manager and I am a new guy? @Unfair-Ban

Comment: @Vincent Hang on, what do you mean by "this manager allow other people to check sensitive thing in untrusted environment"? Are you now trying to say that the manager told the colleague to access your computer?

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't bother to include your location, I'll assume you're in the US (though the answer applies for most western countries).

During probation you can be dismissed for essentially no reason (if you're in an at will state, this applies even after probation). Discrimination is illegal of course but unless someone found out you were part of a protected group after you were hired and you can show the link (which isn't the case here or you'd have mentioned it), this is irrelevant here.

Additionally, you did do something wrong. You left your screen unlocked with sensitive information on display. This is almost certainly violating a security policy- consider it a favour that they used a generic reason rather than fired you over a security breach.

Your best move is to find a new job. If asked about this one, you don't need to give details- just say you left during probation.

If you absolutely cannot let this lie, speak to an employment attorney. If you are part of a union, they will likely provide legal advice. If not, many attorneys offer free initial consultation. If you have a case, they will advise you of your next steps.

Besides that, what happens to your manager is the company's decision. If they either don't agree with your assessment or if they side with the manager, there's not much that can happen.

Comment: Actually I am considering send email to everyone in the team, telling them be careful on someone, ask them must close screen when leave seat.

Comment: @Vincent I'd recommend against that. Publicly airing things like that will make you look petty to everyone. You're also publicly admitting that you made a security breach so if you had any legal options before that, you certainly wouldn't afterward.

You'll also look foolish because "don't leave your screen unlocked with sensitive information on it" is the IT equivalent of "look before crossing the street".